# In C++, can I skip defining assignment operator after defining my own copy constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

When I define a class, I need to define my own copy constructor if I need deep-copy.
Then, is it necessary to define the assignment operator as well? 
If it is skipped, does the assignment do shallow copy?

Comment: How about you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @freakish It is not recommended to learn C++ by trial and error. Sure, you can check if the compiler rejects your code (in which case you can be quite sure the code is wrong) but you can't confirm the validity of code that way.

Comment: @MaxLanghof you mean **you** don't recommend. This question can be easily resolved by a simple check. So we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @freakish the behaviour *in this case* can be learned by observation. In other cases "try it and see what happens" results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @freakish what if OP tries with fields that have deep copy semantic...

Comment: @Caleth lucky for us, we are not dealing with those other, not-present-here cases.

Comment: @freakish But if you advise "try it and see" in one case, and that gets interpreted as general advice, you are teaching a dangerous habit. Hence Max's advice "It is not recommended to learn C++ by trial and error"

Comment: @Caleth if one applies an advice to every possible scenario, then perhaps he should reconsider being a programmer. That is a lot more dangerous.

Comment: @freakish "try it and see" is reasonable general advice for learning, not just for programmers, because there are many situations where it *is* suitable. C++ so happens to be one of the rare occasions where it *isn't* suitable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you need. This is known as the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)): when one of copy-ctor, assignment-operator or dtor is defined, the two others must probably be defined. Exceptions exists but in standard cases, you must...

Since C++11, [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedi0.org/wiki/Talk:Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_three_becomes_rule_of_five_in_C++0x) applies to tackle the move semantics.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally preferable to define data members such that you *don't* need to write a copy constructor (nor a copy assignment operator).

Instead of

```
class Foo {
    Bar * data = nullptr;
public:
    explicit Foo(const Bar & x) : data(new Bar(x)) {}
    ~Foo() { delete data; }
    Foo(const Foo & other) : data(new Bar(*other.data)) {}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo & other) { delete data; data = new Bar(*other.data); return *this; }
};
```

You have

```
class Foo {
    Bar data;
public:
    explicit Foo(const Bar & x) : data(x) {}
};
```

This is known as the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)